# Is a default-generated constructor not required to construct all base classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, clang, default-copy-constructor

I've come across a case in which type-safe c++ produces non-matching ctor/dtors. 
The following code generates two constructors for A. The default constructor also constructs its base (B), but the default-generated copy/move ctor does not construct B. Later, it destroys B, so we get non-matching ctor/dtor.

I've tried this with gcc and clang and both fail. In the gcc bug report forum they suggested this isn't a gcc problem. 
I may be missing something, but isn't there something odd when type-safe code results in a dtor call for a class that hasn't been constructed?

### Program output:

```
B() -> INSERT: 0x7fff55398b2f
~B() -> ERASE: 0x7fff55398b2f
~B() -> ERASE: 0x7fff55398b40         // <- unmatched dtor call 
Assertion failed: (!all.empty()), function ~B, file gcc_bug.c, line 20.
```

Code follows:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>
#include <experimental/optional>


std::set<std::uintptr_t> all;

struct B
{
    B()
    {
        std::cerr << "B() -> INSERT: " << this << "\n";
        all.insert((std::uintptr_t)this);
    }
    ~B()
    {
        std::cerr << "~B() -> ERASE: " << this << "\n";
        assert(!all.empty());                                // FAILS
        assert(all.find((std::uintptr_t)this) != all.end()); // FAILS
        all.erase((std::uintptr_t)this);
    }
};
struct A : B {};

static std::experimental::optional<A> f()
{
    A a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = f();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `B` being created by the implicitly defined copy constructor.  This, of course, is not calling `B::B()`.  If you add the following constructor:

```
B(const B& other) : B()
{
    *this = other;
}
```

you will see the output:

```
B() -> INSERT: 0x7ffe57ef918f
B() -> INSERT: 0x7ffe57ef91b0
~B() -> ERASE: 0x7ffe57ef918f
~B() -> ERASE: 0x7ffe57ef91b0
```

The important point to take away is this: *every* constructor completely constructs the object.  By default, a copy constructor will not call the default constructor (and, obviously, vice versa).  Therefore if you have something that needs to be done in every constructor, you must explicitly do that in every constructor, either by direct call, or by constructor chaining.

Comment: What you say certainly fixes it, but I'm still amazed that if one forgets to define a copy/move ctor for B then you can get type-safe code (no casts etc.) that destroys unconstructed memory! This seems to me like an issue.

Comment: Is there some c++ guru that we could point this out to (perhaps yourself)? They may be able to clarify it or bubble it up.

Comment: @user2059893 Edited to expound a little.  There is no unconstructed memory here.  An implicit copy constructor is still a constructor.

Comment: @user2059893 The destructor is never called on an unconstructed object.  The object created by the implicit copy constructor _is_ constructed.  It just doesn't call the code that is in your default constructor.  It still creates an object with a valid `this` pointer, and when it leaves scope, it will still call its destructor.  Maybe you mean something different by "constructed".  If you mean an object is "constructed" if it calls the code in your default constructor, then it _is_ "unconstructed", but it would be better to say that it hasn't been properly _initialized_.

Comment: @user2059893: "*I'm still amazed that if one forgets to define a copy/move ctor for B then you can get type-safe code (no casts etc.) that destroys unconstructed memory!*" - that is why idioms like [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) and [Rule of Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)#Rule_of_Five) exist. You need to learn them. And then learn to use RAII wrappers that allow you to not have to worry so much about those rules because they get handled for you.

Comment: I certainly know of those guidelines, they are definitely good practice. I somehow never before came across a case where harmless-looking c++ with no unsafe type casts etc. can lead to destructors being called on unconstructed objects. Maybe the designers had good reasons for it that I'm unaware of.

Comment: You keep saying "unconstructed".  I do not think this means what you think it means.

Comment: Ah, ok, md5i's reply answers the question. Good to know it was a misunderstanding.

Comment: @md5i yes, I now see what you were saying. *some* constructor was called, this means there is no safety issue. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This was a silly question. I should get some sleep. Thanks all for your patience.